# Get certain columnheader in the same position in all sheets VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a lot of sheets containing a different number of columns. In each sheet is a column with the header "TOTAL.x", where x is the number of the sheet. I'm trying to find the TOTAL column in each sheet and move it to the same position, so when the sheets are merged into one sheet all TOTAL columns are in the same column.

Here is a minimal example of the sheets to better explain, what I'm trying to obtain:

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Sheet3:

[image]

In the above example the goal would be to have the TOTAL column moved to column G in all sheets. Which is equivalent to inserting a varying number of empty columns before the TOTAL column in each sheet, respectively 1, 4 and 0.

It can be divided in the following two tasks:

1. Finding the TOTAL column in each sheet and move it to a column right of the largest data range. (In the above example any column right to column G)
2. In each sheet check if column A is empty, if it's empty in all sheets delete it in all sheets if not move to next column continue to the column chosen for task1.

I almost have task1:

```
Sub Task1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    Dim search As Range
    Set search = Rows("1:1").Find("TOTAL", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not search Is Nothing Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        search.EntireColumn.Cut
        Columns("J").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next
starting_ws.Activate
End Sub
```

**Question1: (SOLVED)**

I can only get it to work if the header of the TOTAL column is "TOTAL" and not when TOTAL is just a prefix of the actual header name respectively "TOTAL.1", "TOTAL.2", and "TOTAL.3". A solution could be either to get it to work with the prefix TOTAL, or replace 'TOTAL.x' with 'TOTAL'.

**Question2:**

I have no idea how check if a certain column is empty in all sheets, and if it's true delete the column in all sheets.

I have tried to solve my problem in a long time, and I look forward to see some ideas and receive some help with the tasks. Any ideas to make the code more elegant or faster is also welcome.

**UPDATE**

Task 1 is now solved.

Comment: Change to `LookAt:=xlpart`.

Comment: @SJR Thank you so much, solved my first task

Comment: For Q2 perhaps use the COUNTA formula?

Comment: @User123456789 I think both task1 and task2 work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of task1, I had to do some fixes to get it to work on my own computer. Here it is and it works perfectly. I am working on task 2 and will post an update.

```
Sub Task1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

For Each ws In Worksheets

    MsgBox "This is fun" & ws.Name

    ws.Activate
    Dim search As Range
    Set search = ws.Rows("1:1").Find("TOTAL", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not search Is Nothing Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        search.EntireColumn.Cut
        ws.Columns("J").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    
    MsgBox "END-This is fun" & ws.Name
Next
starting_ws.Activate
End Sub
```

### Update

For task 2, I am using the CountA and doing a proof of concept.
Here it is, seems to work on my PC:

```
Sub Task2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

Dim deleteColumn As Boolean

Dim totalColumnsToCheck
Dim currentIterations

totalColumnsToCheck = 20
currentIterations = 0

For c = 1 To totalColumnsToCheck

    deleteColumn = True

    For Each ws In Worksheets
    
         ws.Activate
        
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Columns(c)) > 0 Then
            deleteColumn = False
        Else
            
        End If

    Next

    If deleteColumn Then
     For Each ws In Worksheets
             ws.Activate
             ws.Columns(c).EntireColumn.Delete
        Next
        totalColumnsToCheck = totalColumnsToCheck - 1
        
        If c > 0 Then
            c = c - 1
        End If
        
    End If
    
    currentIterations = currentIterations + 1
    
    If currentIterations > totalColumnsToCheck Then
        Exit For
    End If

Next c


starting_ws.Activate


End Sub
```